# is it possible to organize validation through a separate parent class in pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I have code, which don't work:

```py
class OrderValidator:
    @validator("product_id")
    def product_exists(cls, product_id):
        print(cls)
        session = create_session()
        order = session.query(Order).get(product_id)

        if order is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Product with the ID: {product_id} is not found")
        return product_id

    @validator("product_quantity")
    def check_quantity(cls, product_quantity, values):
        session = create_session()
        product = session.query(Product).get(values["product_id"])

        if product.quantity < product_quantity:
            raise ValueError(
                f"This product does not have such a quantity: {product_quantity}"
            )
        return product_quantity


class CreateOrder(BaseModel, OrderValidator):
    product_id: int
    product_quantity: int

    contact_whatsapp: str
    contact_telegram: str
    contact_phone: str
    contact_name: str
    contact_city: str

    status = 0


class EditOrder(BaseModel, OrderValidator):
    product_id: Optional[int]
    product_quantity: Optional[int]

    contact_whatsapp: Optional[str]
    contact_telegram: Optional[str]
    contact_phone: Optional[str]
    contact_name: Optional[str]
    contact_city: Optional[str]

    status: Optional[int]
```

**I want to create all the validation logic in one class that pydantic models will inherit.** But my code doesn't work.
P.S.: If one of the validation points is shoved directly into the model, then everything will work fine

Comment: You should never just state that something "doesn't work" without providing the full error or explaining what you mean, like "I tried this... expected this... And got the following..." In this case I happened to guess, what you meant, but it just isn't very nice to ask questions this way. Also you should first reduce your code to a minimal reproducible example and avoid irrelevant details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way the Pydantic `ModelMetaclass` is set up, validators will only ever be inherited from parent classes that are themselves models, i.e. inherit from `BaseModel`. ([Source](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.2/pydantic/main.py#L137))

This means you can easily solve your problem by just having `OrderValidator` inherit from `BaseModel`. Beware however that since the fields that it validates aren't defined on it, you'll need to set [`check_fields=False`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#field-checks) on each validator.

I suppose you might as well turn it into your base model for the others at this point, so that you don't have to inherit from `BaseModel` again. But you know better what the inheritence logic should be.